# Current flow in absence of a potential difference

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

What if at two different points in a wire connected to a system of capacitors and resistors, the electric potential is equal. Will the current flow? There is also a battery connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect a battery to a series of resistors, then you can easily calculate the current flowing through the circuit. If you place a (perfect) voltmeter across a particular resistor $R$ that carries a current $I$ it will measure the p.d. across the resistor as $I \times R$. However, if you place the voltmeter across a piece of wire (with zero resistance) it will register a zero p.d, say $V_{wire}$. This is actually consistent with the above, since you have $V_{wire} = I \times R_{wire}$ with $R_{wire} = 0$. In practice a piece of wire will have a very small resistance (perhaps $\mu \Omega$?) and there will be a corresponding very small p.d. acrossit.